# innerHTML showing the function, not the return value of the function

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, anonymous-function

Trying to DRY up some old javascript I wrote.

**test()**

```js
function test() {
    var output = function() {
        return ajaxPost("test.php", "testvar=bananas");
    }
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = output;
}
```

**ajaxPost()**

```js
function ajaxPost(file,stuff) {
    var xmlhttp;
    var actionFile = file;
    var ajaxVars = stuff;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            // Waiting...
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", actionFile, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.send(ajaxVars);
}
```

The output that I am receiveing is this:

```html
<div id="main">
    function () { return ajaxPost("test.php", "testvar=bananas"); }
</div>
```

I can't figure out why it's sticking the function in the div instead of what the function is supposed to actually do. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your script won't work either way due to the asynchronous nature of ajax. You need to make setting innerHTML asynchronous as well.

Comment: Right... how? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to execute the function by adding `()` to it, else you receive the function body!

```
function test() {
    var output = function() {
        return ajaxPost("test.php", "testvar=bananas");
    }
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = output();
}
```

Furthermore you try to return a value from the AJAX call here

```
 return xmlhttp.responseText;
```

This wont work as in an asynchronous call there is nothing that catches the returned value!
You should call some kind of callback, which uses the returned value.

---

**EDIT**

This would be a callback approach similar to your code:

```
function test( data ) {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = data;
}

function ajaxPost(file,stuff,cb) {

    // ...

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            cb( xmlhttp.responseText );
        } else {
            // Waiting...
        }
    }
    // ...
}

// make the actual call
ajaxPost("test.php", "testvar=bananas", test);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use a callback to do this?

Comment: Just put the functionality, you want to appear after the AJAX call in a separate function and call this function instead of the `return` statement.

Comment: Are you talking about inside the `ajaxPost()` ?

Comment: That sounds logically backwards to what I'm trying to do though. I guess I'll have to pass parameters into the `ajaxPost()` instead of getting results out of it from another function.